# How to obtain the day of the week in a 3 letter format from a datetime object in python?

Tags: python

I am working on a script were I must work with datetime objects in Python. At some point I have one of those objects and I need to get the day of the week (which is a number value) in a 3-letter format (i.e. Tue, Wed, etc.). Here is a brief sample of the code, in dateMatch.group() all I am doing is getting pieces of a string obtained via regex matching.

```
from datetime import datetime

day = dateMatch.group(2)
month = dateMatch.group(3)
year = dateMatch.group(4)
hour = dateMatch.group(5)
minute = dateMatch.group(6)
second = dateMatch.group(7)

tweetDate = datetime(int(year), months[month], int(day), int(hour), int(minute), int(second))
```

From that date time object I get a numerical day value (i.e. 18) and I need to convert it to (i.e. Tue).

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

> date, datetime, and time objects all support a `strftime(format)` method, to create a string representing the time under the control of an explicit format string.
>
> ...
>
> %a — Locale’s abbreviated weekday name.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%a')
   'Wed'
```

Answer (score 7):

The [`strftime` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) of a [`datetime` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) uses the [current locale](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) to determine the conversion.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> t = datetime.now()
>>> t.strftime('%a')
'Tue'
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR')
'fr_FR'
>>> t.strftime('%a')
'Mar'
```

If this is not acceptable (for example, if you're formatting a date for transmission over an Internet protocol, you may actually require the string `Tue` regardless of the user's locale), then you need something like:

```
weekdays = 'Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun'.split()
return weekdays[datetime.now().weekday()]
```

Or you could explicitly request the "C" locale:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'C')
return datetime.now().strftime('%a')
```

but setting the locale like this affects all formatting operations on all threads in your program, so it might not be such a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The doc I used:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

First you need todays date:

```
today = date.today() # Which returns a date object
```

The weekday can be found from a date object by using:

```
weekday = today.timetuple()[6] # Getting the 6th item in the tuple returned by timetuple
```

This returns days since Monday (0 would be Monday), using this integer you can do the following:

```
print ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"][weekday] # Prints out the weekday in three chars
```

Combined you get:

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today() # Gets the date in format "yyyy-mm-ddd"
print today
weekday = today.timetuple()[6] # Gets the days from monday
print ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"][weekday] # Prints out the weekday in three chars
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"], try:

```
import calendar
weekdays = [x for x in calendar.day_abbr]  # in the current locale
```